# Laravel 5 Form not found fatal error

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I have done following process for resolving the error.

-I have added "illuminate/html": "5.*" to composer.json and ran "composer update"
-I have added following to config/app.php
       'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

- but my whole project is not working.Not running.It seems that it is composer issue.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am correct the `illuminate/html` package isn't supported in laravel 5 anymore. There is a community fork at `laravelcollective/html`, see their [site](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) for all documentation.

You could swap the illuminate package for the laravelcollective package:

Add to your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

Add provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
],
```